# How to find text in files and only keep the respective matching lines using the terminal on OS X?

Tags: shell, grep, find

I am pretty new to the terminal and command lines, from what I have found out grep seems to be the right tool to search files for specific text strings.

I have a folder with many huge text files and I would like to only keep those lines of each file that contain a certain string (e.g. "/foobar"., for instance:

file content:

```
lorem ipsum
trololo /foobar abc
dolor sit
/foobar def
```

shall afterwards be:

```
trololo /foobar abc
/foobar def
```

I guess the command looks something like this

```
grep -wE "(/foobar)"
```

but I have no clue how to tell the command to only keep those lines and do that for each file that you find in the current folder.

Would you do that with `find` or does grep have an own functionality for that? Something like:

```
find ./* -exec do grep stuff here
```

Comment: Line number 1 to 4 is in your file or it is your simulation?

Comment: grep has a recursive option `-R`

Comment: -1 Why is `2. foobar def` in the result when it doesn't include the specified string `/foobar`?

Comment: @RobinA.Meade youre downvoting my question because of that? Cheers mate!

Comment: @Alex I changed to an upvote after most recent edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` would only find lines matching a pattern in a file, it wouldn't change the file.  You could use `sed` to find the pattern and make changes to the file:

```
sed '/\B\/foobar\b/!d' filename
```

would display lines matching `/foobar` in the file.  In order to save changes to the file in-place, use the `-i` option.

```
sed -i '/\B\/foobar\b/!d' filename
```

You could use it with `find` too:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i'' '/\B\/foobar\b/!d' {} \;
```

Comment: `find . -type f -exec find ./* -exec sed -i '/\B\/foobar\b/!d' {} \;` errors: `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`

Comment: `find ./* -exec sed -i '/\B\/foobar\b/!d' {} \;`errors `sed: 1: "./myfile": invalid command code .`

Comment: still use this pretty often by the way, so powerful and fast. thanks again