# How come sed is so fast?

Tags: files, sed, performance

I thought about whether this question is suitable for SE or not, I hope you agree it is.

Some time ago I asked on SE how to find text in files and leave the file with only the matching lines that contain the text I was searching for. The question is here:  [How to find text in files and only keep the respective matching lines using the terminal on OS X?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129519/how-to-find-text-in-files-and-only-keep-the-respective-matching-lines-using-the)

While the answer worked perfectly I now wonder, how come `sed` is so fast? In my use case, I had quite a lot of files which in total were about 30 Gb in size. The `sed` command ran in about 12 seconds which I never would have believed (working with a normal HDD). Within 12 seconds the command read through 30 Gb of text, truncating each file to only keep the respective lines I was filtering for. **How does this work?** (or: what is this sorcery?)

The actual command was:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i'' '/\B\/foobar\b/!d' {} \;
```

Comment: What command you actually ran?

Comment: `find . -type f -exec sed -i'' '/\B\/foobar\b/!d' {} \;`

Comment: This seems like a rather general question. What kind of answer were you looking for? sed is written in C, and presumably optimized for speed.

Comment: For a general answer :-) but more indepth maybe, some technical aspects, what it does that is it so fast? If there is a better place to ask this please advice me so

Comment: You can read the source for GNU sed: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/ (I understand that being on OSX you're not using GNU sed)

Comment: I understand that the question might be unclear in terms of "unclear what youre asking" or there are too many ways to answer this. however, i cant read C and I dont want read through the code, I was just wondering if there is an easy, bold explanation of what sed does (maybe if there is a trick or something very beautiful in how it masters performance), not too technical but not too broad either. if this is not the case, please close the question :)

Comment: Related: [How does `grep` run so fast?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12629749/3960947) and (maybe) [Does `grep` work faster with long or short search terms?](http://superuser.com/q/592411/354511)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely answer is that:

1. The 30Gb file was not fragmented (or had very little fragmentation): all hard drives perform much better with sequential access (SSDs included) because they are able to cache large chunks of the file. This allows them to approach their maximum performance. Sequential access will help with all levels of caches.
2. `sed` is a stream editor; it only processes one line at a time. This means that its memory footprint is minuscule. Unlike a text editor such as `emacs` or `vim`, it does not need to maintain the entire copy of the file in memory.
3. You are editing the file in-place (with `-i`) which (as demonstrated by @Ramesh and also stated on [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed#In-place_editing)) creates a temporary files which then becomes the old file.

All of this means that `sed` is able to perform almost the bare minimum of file operations: each line of the original file is read once, and only the lines that are matched are written.

Your choice of regular expressions also impacts performance, sometimes in very bad ways.: [coding horror blog](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/).

Answer (score 3):

One wonderful example is `sed` uses a temporary file to actually save the contents and then replaces the original file. For example, you can do a simple testing to find this.

```
cat test
This is a test file.
```

Now, run `ls -li` to check the inode number.

```
ls -li test
2368770 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22 Sep 12 08:46 test
```

Now, issue the below `sed` command to add a blank line.

```
sed -i 's/2/B/' test
```

After changing the file, issue the `ls` command again and check the inode number.

```
ls -li test
2368753 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22 Sep 12 08:48 test
```

We can see that the inode number has infact changed. So instead of copying to the same file `sed` creates a new temporary file and copies the contents to the new temp file and then deletes the original file and renames the tmp file in sync with the original file which is one reason why the file operations are really faster.

Quoting from [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed#Mode_of_operation),

> sed is a line-oriented text processing utility: it reads text, line by
>   line, from an input stream or file, into an internal buffer called the
>   pattern space. Each line read starts a cycle. To the pattern space,
>   sed applies one or more operations which have been specified via a sed
>   script. sed implements a programming language with about 25 commands
>   that specify the operations on the text. For each line, after running
>   the script sed ordinarily outputs the pattern space (the input line as
>   modified by the script) and begins the cycle again with the next line.

To understand more on the pattern space and hold space concepts of `sed`, you should read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12834372/1742825).

> When sed reads a file line by line, the line that has been currently
>   read is inserted into the pattern buffer (pattern space). Pattern
>   buffer is like the temporary buffer, the scratchpad where the current
>   information is stored. When you tell sed to print, it prints the
>   pattern buffer.
>
> Hold buffer / hold space is like a long-term storage, such that you
>   can catch something, store it and reuse it later when sed is
>   processing another line. You do not directly process the hold space,
>   instead, you need to copy it or append to the pattern space if you
>   want to do something with it.